# Where can I find advanced crossword puzzles relating to specific themes, e.g. history?

Tags: crosswords

Where can I find crossword puzzles with a specific theme, e.g. history, geography, etc. that are at a level suitable for an adult? I realize that something like history is a very general category, but even if the clues are a hodge-podge, that's fine with me.

I've used search engines to look for puzzles like this, but almost everything I can find is either designed for a classroom and thus geared towards children, or user-generated and far too simple. ([This](http://www.whenwecrosswords.com/crossword/atomic_bombings_of_hiroshima_and_nagasaki/1389/crossword_answer.jsp) is one absolutely atrocious example).

[This meta question](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/3129/13393) is relevant to questions of this type.

---

In response to the comments, I'm interested in puzzles for myself. The topics I listed above, like history and geography, are some of the themes I'm interested in; once again, I realize these are quite general categories.

Comment: What is the purpose of your search? Do you want to get challenges *for yourself* or do you want to use them elsewhere *for others*? I'm asking, because if the latter than help on *creating* such puzzle might be a helpful answer, but obviously not in the first case... And out of curiosity: Why a specific theme - and which one?

Comment: Do you accept any type of grid? Check here for the different layouts: https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Crossword

Comment: With any luck this site itself will eventually become a great place to go for exactly those kinds of things.

Answer (score 1):

Virgilius in the Independent and Brendan in Guardian are two setters who regularly set themed puzzles. Themed daily puzzles published in British crosswords can be found at [this link](http://www.fifteensquared.net/?s=themed).

The Hindu Crossword also features themed puzzles once in a while. These can be looked up in [this link](http://www.thehinducrosswordcorner.blogspot.com).